# Get the last entered value of editText when using TextWatcher

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

TextWatcher helps me save the values on scrolling down the recyclable view. But when I want to store the last entered value by the user in an ArrayList.
on adding values to ArrayList all values that have been entered to the textView get added but I only want the last one. Please help me, I'm new to android and stuck.

utils is a class that I have defined within which is the Qstrips ArrayList which I want to access somewhere else.

```
editstrip.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            inputValuesStrips.put(p2strip, s.toString());
            int t = 0;
            try {
                t = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                t = 0;
            }
            if (t <= stock.getStrips()) {
                double cal = t * stock.getmrp();
                TotalCost = TotalCost + cal;
                utils.Qstrips.add(cal);
            } else {
                editstrip.setError("Only " + stock.getStrips() + " in one box!");
                editstrip.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm assuming inputValuesStrips is your ArrayList. Do I understand correctly, that you try to only put the part that changed/was added into that ArrayList?

Comment: If so you probably realized, that the Editable Parameter s in afterTextChanged, is the whole content of the EditText. To only adress the changes you rather want to use onTextChange, since its Parameters help you distinguish the new changes from the old text.